# Snabackbar con 2 iconos-Android

Tags: android

tengo planeado montar una snackbar, la cual me gustaría que se visualizarán 2 iconos, pero siguiendo el siguiente formato:

```
 String + icon + String /n String + icon  + String
```

por lo que debiera ser un titulo, el icono y una pequeña descripción, ademas de una separación, para volver al mismo formato y repetirlo una vez más, es posible, realizar lo mencionado?

---

edit:

```
Snackbar snackbar=  Snackbar.make(v1,"Valoracion: "+icono+"/n"+icono+"reporte: accidente"+"/n"+"descripcion: en la mitad de la via",12000)
                          .setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
                          .setAction("Opciones", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                            .setIcon(R.drawable.cerrar)
                                            .setTitle("Opciones")
                                            .setMessage("Te gustaria valorar o reportar la ruta?")
                                            .setCancelable(true)
                                            .setPositiveButton("Valorar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Valoracion2.class);
                                                    i.putExtra("Nruta", marker.getTitle().toString());
                                                    startActivity(i);
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null)
                                            .setNegativeButton("Reportar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){

                                                }
                                            }).show();
                                }
                            });
                    View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setMaxLines(5);
                    snackbar.show();
```

Comment: quisieras concatenar iconos con string?? podrías mostrar el código que tenes hecho?

Comment: @josego, exactamente, lo subo en un segundo

Comment: sabes si es posible realizar lo que necesito?

Comment: no se. Debería de probar.